# SQL Update a table after comparing value with another table

Tags: sql-server, join, compare

I have 3 tables involved in this scenario. Table1 (a temp table) has some order numbers. table2 has details about those(and all other) orders but maybe missing data in a few fields. table3 has those missing details.

what I need to do is, select each order from table2 that are in table1. There could be one or multiple orders in table1. So for those orders, I need to go and check table3.fieldx and see if there are any contents there. if not null, copy table3.fieldx to table2.fieldx.

some help would be appreciated.

sample table and data here
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02947

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: sample table and data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02947

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the sqlfiddle. With sample data this is actually something we can help with.

Think you want something like this.

```
update t2
set fieldx = ISNULL(t3.fieldx, t2.fieldx)
from #table2 t2
join #table1 t1 on t1.ord_num = t2.ord_num
left join #table3 t3 on t3.ord_num = t2.ord_num
```

Comment: Sean, Thanks for your solution. I have a slight change in the data. I've updated sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6cee5 with my changes. This will probably change the relationship a bit. Please let me know your input.

Comment: It is still pretty much the same thing. My concern is that if you are unable to adjust the query to your new data structures then you don't really understand what this is doing. Keep in mind that you need to support this query and it will be your phone that rings at 3am when production is not working. How about if you give it shot and see if you can get it.

Comment: Sean, I actually did.                                                                               update ord
set fieldx = ISNULL(dtl.fieldx, ord.fieldx)
 from #ord ord
 join #temp1 tmp on tmp.po_num = ord.po_num
 left join #ord_dtl dtl on dtl.ord_num = tmp.ord_num and dtl.line_num = tmp.line_num

Comment: OK. So what is the goal now? You have a query that seems to be syntactically correct. From what I understand of your logic it seems to be correct. Can you explain what isn't working correctly? What is the desired output from your sample data?

Comment: I don't think my query have any issues. I'm trying to test this and make sure I have everything in place.

Comment: I am confused. You already have it working as you expect it to?

Comment: with the changes I made in the version I posted above, I'm trying to get that tested. I'd like to concatenate a string before the value that is being added if the field is null. so, if t3.fieldx is not null, I'd like to update t2.fieldx with this value: 'mystring'+t3.fieldx. How do I achieve that?

Comment: basic string concatenation, 'mystring'+t3.fieldx

Comment: here's what I did: set t2.fieldx = case when t3.fieldx is null or t3.fieldx  = '' then null else 'mystring:'+t3.fieldx end

Comment: ok. is that not doing what you want it to? I am lost as to what you need help with here.

Comment: Sean, I believe it's doing what it's supposed to. I was just running it by you to see if it can be improved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Looks to be fine to me. If this answer helped, you might consider marking it as the answer.